# How to extract the BGR values inside the detected Hough Circles in opencv python?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to detect the BGR values inside the lens of an eye. Initially, I've tried to detect the lens using cv2.HoughCircles. Now, How do I use the detected circle and extract color features inside it.

And if I simply print the detected circles, for example
**print(circles)**
the output gives..
**[[[148,123,48]]]**

How can I use the above array for my extraction?

Thanks.

Comment: x=148, y=126, radius=48. Draw a white mask with `cv::circle` on a black image, and get BGR values only inside the mask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Just one basic question. How can I split the array values of this dimension in python... [[[148,123,48]]] to different variables x,y,r. 
For example, I tried with...
x,y,r = circles
It shows some error because of some incompatible dimension and shape.

Comment: try this `x,y,z = circles[0][0]`